# Advanced MySQL: Find correlations between poll responses

Tags: mysql, sql, correlation

I've got four MySQL tables:

**users** (id, name)
**polls** (id, text)
**options** (id, poll_id, text)
**responses** (id, poll_id, option_id, user_id)

Given a particular poll and a particular option, I'd like to generate a table that shows which options from other polls are most strongly correlated.

Suppose this is our data set:

```
TABLE users:
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | Abe   |
|    2 | Bob   |
|    3 | Che   |
|    4 | Den   |
+------+-------+

TABLE polls:
+------+-----------------------+
| id   | text                  |
+------+-----------------------+
|    1 | Do you like apples?   |
|    2 | What is your gender?  |
|    3 | What is your height?  |
|    4 | Do you like polls?    |
+------+-----------------------+

TABLE options:

+------+----------+---------+
| id   | poll_id  | text    |
+------+----------+---------+
|    1 | 1        | Yes     |
|    2 | 1        | No      |
|    3 | 2        | Male    |
|    4 | 2        | Female  |
|    5 | 3        | Short   |
|    6 | 3        | Tall    |
|    7 | 4        | Yes     |
|    8 | 4        | No      |
+------+----------+---------+

TABLE responses:

+------+----------+------------+----------+
| id   | poll_id  | option_id  | user_id  |
+------+----------+------------+----------+
|    1 | 1        | 1          | 1        |
|    2 | 1        | 2          | 2        |
|    3 | 1        | 2          | 3        |
|    4 | 1        | 2          | 4        |
|    5 | 2        | 3          | 1        |
|    6 | 2        | 3          | 2        |
|    7 | 2        | 3          | 3        |
|    8 | 2        | 4          | 4        |
|    9 | 3        | 5          | 1        |
|   10 | 3        | 6          | 2        |
|   10 | 3        | 5          | 3        |
|   10 | 3        | 6          | 4        |
|   10 | 4        | 7          | 1        |
|   10 | 4        | 7          | 2        |
|   10 | 4        | 7          | 3        |
|   10 | 4        | 7          | 4        |
+------+----------+------------+----------+
```

Given the poll ID 1 and the option ID 2, the generated table should be something like this:

```
+----------+------------+-----------------------+
| poll_id  | option_id  | percent_correlated    |
+----------+------------+-----------------------+
| 4        | 7          | 100                   |
| 2        | 3          | 66.66                 |
| 3        | 6          | 66.66                 |
| 2        | 4          | 33.33                 |
| 3        | 5          | 33.33                 |
| 4        | 8          | 0                     |
+----------+------------+-----------------------+
```

So basically, we're identifying all of the users who responded to poll ID 1 and selected option ID 2, and we're looking through all the other polls to see what percentage of them also selected each other option.

Comment: I know these tables aren't perfectly optimized -- please ignore that, unless it would significantly affect the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have an instance handy to test, can you see if this gets proper results:

```
select
        poll_id,
        option_id,
        ((psum - (sum1 * sum2 / n)) / sqrt((sum1sq - pow(sum1, 2.0) / n) * (sum2sq - pow(sum2, 2.0) / n))) AS r,
        n
from
(
    select 
        poll_id,
        option_id,
        SUM(score) AS sum1,
        SUM(score_rev) AS sum2,
        SUM(score * score) AS sum1sq,
        SUM(score_rev * score_rev) AS sum2sq,
        SUM(score * score_rev) AS psum,
        COUNT(*) AS n
    from
    (
            select 
                responses.poll_id, 
                responses.option_id,
                CASE 
                    WHEN user_resp.user_id IS NULL THEN SELECT 0
                    ELSE SELECT 1
                END CASE as score,
                CASE 
                    WHEN user_resp.user_id IS NULL THEN SELECT 1
                    ELSE SELECT 0
                END CASE as score_rev,
            from responses left outer join 
                    (
                        select 
                            user_id
                        from 
                            responses 
                        where
                            poll_id = 1 and 
                            option_id = 2
                    )user_resp  
                        ON (user_resp.user_id = responses.user_id)
    ) temp1 
    group by
        poll_id,
        option_id
)components
```

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of trial and error, I managed to put together a query that works correctly:

```
SELECT poll_id AS p_id, 
       option_id AS o_id, 
       COUNT(*) AS optCount, 

       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM response WHERE option_id = o_id AND user_id IN 
          (SELECT user_id FROM response WHERE poll_id = '1' AND option_id = '2')) /
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM response WHERE poll_id = p_id  AND user_id IN 
          (SELECT user_id FROM response WHERE poll_id = '1' AND option_id = '2')) 
       AS percentage 

FROM response 
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT user_id FROM response WHERE poll_id = '1' AND option_id = '2') AS user_ids
ON response.user_id = user_ids.user_id
WHERE poll_id != '1' 

GROUP BY option_id DESC 
ORDER BY percentage DESC, optCount DESC
```

Based on a tests with a small data set, this query looks to be reasonably fast, but I'd like to modify it so the "IN" subquery is not repeated three times.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to give the right results for me:

```
select poll_stats.poll_id,
       option_stats.option_id,
       (100 * option_responses / poll_responses) as percent_correlated
from (select response.poll_id,
             count(*) as poll_responses
      from response selecting_response
           join response on response.user_id = selecting_response.user_id
      where selecting_response.poll_id = 1 and selecting_response.option_id = 2
      group by response.poll_id) poll_stats
      join (select options.poll_id,
                   options.id as option_id,
                   count(response.id) as option_responses
            from options
                 left join response on response.poll_id = options.poll_id
                           and response.option_id = options.id
                           and exists (
                            select 1 from response selecting_response
                            where selecting_response.user_id = response.user_id
                                  and selecting_response.poll_id = 1
                                  and selecting_response.option_id = 2)
            group by options.poll_id, options.id
           ) as option_stats
       on option_stats.poll_id = poll_stats.poll_id
where poll_stats.poll_id <> 1
order by 3 desc, option_responses desc
```