# Constructing a simple recommendation engine

Tags: php, mysql

Both users and pages on my website have IDs. When a user goes on a certain page, their userID and the pageID will be written to a MySQL table as such:

```
 userID | pageID
    3   |    1
    2   |    1
    3   |    2
       etc...
```

In this table, called `user_pages`, I would end up with a bunch of raw data that can be turned into a recommendation engine. What I mean by recommendation engine - I want to analyze historical data, and be able to predict, based on a set of viewed pages, the next pages that a user may like. Let's say there is a strong correlation between visiting page with ID 3 after going to pages with IDs 4, 9, 15. If a user goes on pages 4, 9, and 15, then the engine should recommend page 3.

I think I have all of the data input code necessary for creating this. How would I write something that analyzes the data for correlation of pages (i.e. almost everyone who visited page 5 visited page 1 also), and somehow use that to predict in the future the pages that a user may end up liking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recommendation systems are a big part of A.I research. I believe you are interested in a collection of algorithms called **collaborative filtering**. Since the netflix prize in 2007 this field has developed greatly. I would recommend going [here](http://www.cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/0607/recommend/recommender/index.html) and having a read. It explains the basic concepts of **recommender systems** in a succinct and clear way and also provides a link to Java source code for an approach to the Netflix project, MemReader. You could examine this source code and extrapolate the basic algorithms for building a recommendation engine.

Alternatively if you want a more mathematical explanation of the algorithms employed go [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wcohen/collab-filtering-tutorial.ppt).

It shouldn't take too long to implement at all.

Comment: Also for open source collaborative filtering projects that are available to deploy, go to http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-collaborative-filter-in-java

Comment: no reasons at all to edit just to add few chars and bump this up

Comment: I edited this answer to improve formatting and highlight key terminology to any passers by.

Answer (score 1):

This post posed a similar question: [Advanced MySQL: Find correlations between poll responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312166/advanced-mysql-find-correlations-between-poll-responses)

I think you would be able to generate a similar response if your primary data table had one additional field in it, specifically the id of the page the used last visited or visited immediately following.

Something like this:

```
+------+----------+--------------+----------+
| id   | page_id  | next_page_id | user_id  |
+------+----------+--------------+----------+
|    1 | 1        | 1            | 1        |
|    2 | 1        | 2            | 2        |
|    3 | 1        | 2            | 3        |
|    4 | 1        | 2            | 4        |
|    5 | 2        | 3            | 1        |
|    6 | 2        | 3            | 2        |
|    7 | 2        | 3            | 3        |
|    8 | 2        | 4            | 4        |
|    9 | 3        | 5            | 1        |
+------+----------+--------------+----------+
```

Then you should be able to use a modified version of one of the SQL queries suggested there to generate a list of high-correlation recommendations between the current page and the next page.